# can I scan for bluetooth devices without turning on the bluetooth adapter?

Tags: android, bluetooth

lets say there are two phones named A and B. The bluetooth adapter of B is turned on and is in discoverable mode. But the BT in phone A is turned off. BUT THEY ARE BOTH PAIRED WITH EACH OTHER.

What I need to know is, when the phone A enters into the bluetooth signal range of phone B, is there a way to automatically establish the connection between each other?
In other words, can phone A keep "listening" for B's bluetooth signal, and as soon as A detects the B is in his range, connect with each other programatically.

Note:- When A enters the bluetooth range of B, A's bt adapter is turned off (for power saving purposes). So A should "listen" for B while A's BT is turned off.

can I use "bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();" to fulfill this requirement? or is there another way?

I'm new to android. I'm an electronics engineering undergraduate. This is a part of my final year project :(

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is no.

In order to establish a connection between the two device, you will need to open a bluetooth socket (Server/client), and to open it, you'll need the bluetooth adapter on each device. (Even if they are already paired.)

I understand that bluetooth adapter and listening socket use a lot of battery, but there is no other option (AFAIK)